# $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational proof using well-Ordering Property

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, rationality-testing

I am having a problem understanding this proof.

Suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ was rational.

Then there would exist positive integers $a,b$ such that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$. Consequently, the set $S=\{k\sqrt{2} : k \text{ and } k\sqrt{2}$ are positive integers $\}$ is nonempty set of positive integers. Therefore, by the well-ordering property, $S$ has a smallest element, say, $s = t \sqrt{2}$.

We have 
$s \sqrt{2}-s = s\sqrt{2}-t\sqrt{2}=(s-t)\sqrt{2}$. 
Because $s\sqrt{2} = 2t$ and $s$ are both integers, 
$s\sqrt{2} - s = s\sqrt{2}-t\sqrt{2} = (s-t)\sqrt{2}$ 
must also be an integer.

Furthermore, it is positive, because $s\sqrt{2}-s = s(\sqrt{2}-1)$ and $\sqrt{2} > 1$.

It is less than $s$, because $\sqrt{2} < 2$ so that $\sqrt{2}-1 < 1$. This contradicts the choice of $s$ as the smallest positive integer in $S$. It follows that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

My main problem here is how they got the set $S$. My second confusion is the algebra part $s \sqrt{2}-s$. How did they come up with this?

If someone can explain this proof to me it would be great! thank you

Comment: Perhaps  my answer to a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497420/how-to-show-if-sqrtn-is-rational-number-then-n-is-a-perfect-square/1497469#1497469) will make it clearer: I use a similar methode to show that if $\sqrt n$ is rational, $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: I liked and upvoted what Bernard did in that link, Surprisingly enough, that answer was not upvoted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that

$$\sqrt2=\frac ab\implies b\sqrt2=a\in\Bbb Z\implies b\in S$$

as defined.

The algebra: observe that the minimal element in $\;S\;$ is $\;\color{red}{s=t\sqrt2}\in\Bbb Z\;$ , thus

$$s\sqrt2-\color{red}s=s\sqrt2-\color{red}{t\sqrt2}=(s-t)\sqrt2\ldots\text{ and etc.}$$

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. Just a quick question, why would you subtract $s\sqrt{2}-s$?

Comment: @EmadZamout Because we can and that's the way they reach a contradiction... :) . Just like with the usual proof by Archimedes: why do you take *coprime* $\;a\,,\,b\;$ in the assumption $\;\sqrt 2=\frac ab\;$ ?  Because we can and that's the way the contradiction is gotten.

Comment: Okay I understand that man but I want to know how they came up with that. If I want to prove similar problems, I need to come up with such equations. I know $s$ is the least element, so they took $s\sqrt{2}-s$. They multiplied it by $\sqrt{2}$ then subtracted $s$ from it.

Comment: How does someone come up with an idea may be difficult to explain: many hours of study, relying on past ideas, etc. In this case, though, as the well ordering of the naturals is going to be used, defining a non-empty set of naturals and then contradicting the fact it has a minimal element seems the "natural" way to go. This is kind of *infinite descent* way to prove things in number theory. Google it.

Comment: Thank you man. It took me a while to fully understand what you mean. :)

Comment: @EmadZamout Good! That's what this is, in my opinion, supposed to be: *some help* so that askers will be able to find the final solution **for themselves**. You're welcome.