# Well Ordering Principle and $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, since I've attended to the introduction to number theory course I couldn't stop thinking about this problem:

**Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational using the Well Ordering Principle.**

Ok, I started defining a set $X = \{ x = z \sqrt{2}; z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and supposing that there exists an $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a < x$, $\forall x \in X$. Hence, there exists an $x' \in X$ such that $ x' \leq x$, $\forall x \in X$.

And that's when I can't proceed further. Is there a problem in the way I've defined the set or it is just a "leap" that I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The well ordering principal only works on subsets of *natural* numbers.  $a \in \mathbb Z$ and the *integers* don't have a least element.  As $a$ *can* be any integer there *isn't* any $a$ so that $a  < x$ for all $x$ in $X$ as $X$ isn't bounded.

Comment: If you require $z \in \mathbb N$ then the $x'$ you want is $\sqrt 2$.  $\sqrt 2 \le z\sqrt 2$ for all $z \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sqrt 2 ~$ is irrational proof using well-Ordering Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965080/sqrt2-is-irrational-proof-using-well-ordering-property).

Comment: I required $X$ to be lower bounded, so there exists a least element on $X$. And yes, you can do this analog version of the WOP, for both lower and upper bounded subsets of $\mathbb{Z}. Maybe I "miswrote" some part in the question about that hahahaha my bad.

Comment: Manoj, I'll read this topic and if it answers my question, I'll end mine. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see what you meant to say:

Let $X = \{x| x\in \mathbb N$ and $x = z\sqrt{2}$ for some natural number $z\}$.

Now if $X$ isn't empty it has a least element $a$.  We want to show that there is an element of $X$ that is smaller than $a$.

The claim is that if $a = b\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb N$, then $c = a - b =b\sqrt 2-b \in X$.

To prove this we must show i) $c$ is an integer (it must be because $a,b$ are integers. ii) $c < a$ (it must be because $b$ is positive)  iii) That $c > 0$  (it must be because $c = b\sqrt 2 -b = b(\sqrt 2 -1)$; As $1 < 2$ we know $1 =\sqrt 1 < \sqrt 2$ so $\sqrt 2 -1 > 0$).  iv) that $c \in X$ or in otherwords that $(b\sqrt 2 - b)\sqrt 2$ is a natural number.

Coming up with $c = a-b = b\sqrt 2 - b$ and proving iv) that is the entire heart of the proof.

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped!

Comment: It looks like you defined $c$ in two different ways. First you defined $c$ as " $c = a - b =b\sqrt 2-b \in X$" and then later "$c \in X$ or in otherwords that $ (b\sqrt 2 - b)\sqrt 2$". I think $c$ should be defined as $ a\sqrt 2 - a = a \sqrt 2  - b\sqrt 2$ ". Overall this proof is confusing.

Comment: Reread it.  $c= a-b=b\sqrt 2-b=b(\sqrt 2 - 1)$ is defined once and once only.   It is never anything else. Step 4) was telling the OP that s/he must prove $c \in X$ or in other words that $c\sqrt 2 = (b\sqrt 2-b)\sqrt=2b -a \in \mathbb N$.  $c \sqrt 2=(b\sqrt 2-b)\sqrt 2=2b-a$ is a *not* $c$. And claiming that we must prove $c\in X$ is not a definition.  It was a statement of what the OP would need to show.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your notation defining the set $X$. What is $x$?

The usual argument goes something like this: let $X$ be the set of positive integers $p$ such that
$$p^2 = 2q^2$$
for some integer $q$. Suppose for contradiction that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational; then $X$ is nonempty, and so by the well-ordering principle has a least element.

Can you see the contradiction from here?

Comment: I think the op is reversing the preposition and the conditional in set definition.  I think the OP means $X = \{x=z\sqrt 2|z\in \mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: I think fleablood answered your first question. About the second part, I can't see the contradiction and I think that's my trouble to progress the problem.

Comment: @user699836 Here's a further hint, then: if $p'$ is the least element of $X$, with $(p')^2 = 2(q')^2$, then $p'$ must be even. What can you conclude about $q'$? Why is this a contradiction?